# Passing Input values from one PHP page to another within hidden fields

Tags: php

```
$sql="SELECT vName,id FROM employee WHERE vName LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY vName";  
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result)
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))

$hid='<input type="hidden" name="xyz" id="abc" value="'.$row['id'].'" />';  
echo($hid);  

echo $row['vName']."\n"; 

}
```

How to pass the value of a hidden input field to another `PHP` script? I am using auto complete. how to pass the value auto complete page to index page

Comment: What is `$row`? And what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Please provide some clarification.

Comment: For pass value to another page you can use php **Session,GET,POST**

Comment: you should use session for that

Answer (score 0):

Create a form

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="xyz" id="abc" value="'.$row['id'].'" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

And Get value on action_page.php

```
$_GET['xyz']
```

You enter your html code inside php code like this

```
<?php
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<form action="action_page.php" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="xyz" id="abc" value="'.$row['id'].'" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
<?php
echo $row['vName']."\n"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: i am using the hidden field in the php form not a html

Comment: You should be using POST not get

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

**Sessions**

[PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

> Session support in PHP consists of a way to preserve certain data across subsequent accesses.

eg:

```
<?php
// Page1.php
session_start();

$_SESSION["key"] = "random value";
```

Then:

```
<?php
// Page2.php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION["key"];

// Output would then be ... random value
```

**POST**

[Using the PHP $_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Taking what you currently have, you'd do:

```
<form method="post" action="somescript.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="xyz" id="abc" value="<?=$row['id'] ?>" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submitForm" />
</form>
```

Then on `somescript.php` if you do:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
```

You'll see an array with the data from your form, hidden value included